# How to write a query to get not equal in AnyLogic?

Tags: anylogic

I need to write a deleteFrom statement to delete data entry which "id" is not equal to 0. May I ask on the syntax?

Can someone help me to correct the following statement?

deleteFrom(db_operators).where(db_operators.id.**eq**(0)).execute();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method for 'not equal' is **ne()**, for other types of comparison see documentation [here](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/connectivity/querying.html) (it's towards the bottom of the page).